# How to delay callout in trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, callout

I  need to write a trigger in which callout is made to external system.If there is any exception i.e 5XX then the next request should be made after 5min from the same trigger and after 5 iteration I need to send a mailer.

Comment: One possibility is an  async framework such as the one in Dan Appleman's 3rd Edition _Advanced Apex_ chapter 7 that has a provision for scheduling async events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. use a future method, is a method that run async. [here it is the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_invoking_future_methods.htm)
2. Mark a record with a flag('I use to use a checkbox') and have secheduled class to process the marked records (I use to use a batch class).[Here doc of batch](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) And Here doc of scheduled class

[Here you have the doc of async process](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_async_overview.htm). It explain when you should use all the async types.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule an apex class that does that work for you:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm